# Socket.io not sending a message to all connected sockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying out node.js and socket.io. I wan't to use to remove a ping function I have to get updates from my server. Here is an example code of what I'm doing:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(),
    io  = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    cp  = require('child_process');

app.listen(8080);

//I check a global value for all the connected users from the php command line
var t = setInterval(function(){
  cp.exec('/usr/bin/php /Users/crear/Projects/MandaFree/symfony api:getRemainingMessages',
    function(err, stdout){
      if (err) {
        io.sockets.emit('error', 'An error ocurred while running child process.');
      } else {
        io.sockets.emit('change', stdout);
      }
      console.log('Remaining messages: ' + stdout);
    });
  }, 3000);

var remaining =  io.of('/getRemainingMessages')
  .on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
  });
```

The Issue here, is that when I call io.sockets.emit() the debug console tells me it is doing something, but it looks like it is not getting to the clients. Because they are doing nothing.

I use to have one interval for every connected client, and when I used socket.emit() it did worked. But it is not the optimal solution.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my client side code.

```
var remaining = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080/getRemainingMessages');
remaining.on('change', function(data){
  console.log('Remaining messages: ' + data );
  $('#count').html(data);
});
remaining.on('error', function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: In your client-side code, are there handlers for both `error` and `change`?  You can include that code here which may help determine the issue.

Comment: @Fosco I updated and added the client side code. It used to work when the loop was on the socket configuration in the server. When I changed it to only one loop and sending the message to every one it stopped working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a very similar issue couple of days back and looks like socket.io had some changes in the API. I have never worked with symfony and am hoping the issues are the same.

I have a working demo of socket.io sending and receiving a message - uploaded to https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo as a reference

Essentially two changes

1. On Server side - changed `socket.on` to `socket.sockets.on`

   ```
   var socket = io.listen(server);
   socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client)
   ```
2. On Client side - URL and port not required as it is autodetected.

   ```
   var socket = io.connect();
   ```

This has been tested using Express 2.5.2 and Socket.io 0.8.7

I have amalgamated your server code with mine, would you be able to try this on the server and my [client javascript](https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo/blob/master/public/main.js) and [client html](https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo/blob/master/public/index.html) just to see if it is working?

```
var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
  var connected = true;

  client.on('message', function(m){
    sys.log('Message received: '+m);
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function(){
    connected = false;
  });

  var t = setInterval(function(){
  if (!connected) {
      return;
  }

  cp.exec('/usr/bin/php /Users/crear/Projects/MandaFree/symfony api:getRemainingMessages',
    function(err, stdout){
      if (err) {
        client.send('error : An error ocurred while running child process.');
      } else {
        client.send('change : ' + stdout);
      }
      console.log('Remaining messages: ' + stdout);
    });
  }, 3000);

  t();

});
```